# AIR for iOS app crashes on iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, air

I am developing an AIR app which packages multiple video files in swf format.
Users of the app are supposed to create a movie by creating a sequence of these swf files. The ipa file size is around 200MB.
I have done some graphic optimizations such as using bitmaps wherever possible, avoid using filters and blend modes etc.
The app works just fine on iOS6/iPad3 however it crashes on iOS5.1/iPad3. After checking device logs using xcode on Mac, it appears that the app is crashing because of low memory. The real problem seems to be loading of swfs which keeps adding on to memory usage with every swf load. The Loader.unload() method does not work on iOS, so it seems that I have hit a dead end. I have no clue as to how to tackle this memory issue without unload.

I tried the latest AIR SDK 3.6 Beta, but the video swfs just don't load and hence I cannot use the application. I had specified loader context with application domain set to current domain. According to adobe labs page they have added support for packaging and loading of multiple swfs and better memory management in AIR 3.6, however until I can load the swf its of no use to me.

I am using following setup:
Flash Professional CS6
AIR SDK 3.5.0.600
iPad 3/iOS 5.1

I would really appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe helpful in your situation either: I had constant crashes when working with video in AIR 3.5. Setting the render mode to direct helped to workaround this bug of the AIR runtime. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not tried that render mode yet. Actual issue seems to be low memory and not the performance but I will still give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mario. Direct render mode does work. The app is not crashing now. :) However would it make any difference if I create the video swfs targeting Flash Player 11 and above. Right now the videos are targeted for Flash Player 10.